# Referencing an array value from in a function in R

Tags: arrays, r

I imagine I am missing something quite simple here, or I am barking up the wrong tree completely, however I have been trying to sort this out over a number of days and my novice R skills haven't been able to crack it.

I am looking for a method to reference an array of values from within a R function. I am creating a simulated population, I have individuals age, sex and ethnicity and I want to simulate the presence of absence of diabetes. I have the prevalence of diabetes by age bracket, gender and ethnicity which I have made into a 2(gender)x11(age bracket)x6(ethnicity) array. What I want to do is the reference the correct cell within the array and used that with a runif called to run a bernoulli trial per individual.

The code below is the current version however I have tried a number of different methods with varying results:

```
function(AB,sex,eth){

AB<-AB
sex<- sex
eth<-as.numeric(eth)


#make matrix reference
#make 'european' equal to 'other'
eth <- ifelse(eth==7,6,eth)
#change male from a 0 coding to a 2 for array lookup
sex <- ifelse(sex==1,1,2)
#remove seven from AB due to diab data starting at 30-34 age bracket
agebracket <- AB-7
#random number drawn
diabbase <- runif(census$Total.Sex[AB],0,1) 
#census$total.sex gives the total number in each age bracket

#array assignment
arrayvalue <- Darray[agebracket,sex,eth]

diab <- ifelse((diabbase >= (Darray[agebracket,sex,eth])) ,1,0)
return(diab)
}
```

if i call the function from the command line with "arrayvalue" returned rather than "diab" and individual values submitted rather than variables (ie diabtest <- diabgen(10,1,1) ) it returns the correct value from the array but if I submit the variables(ie diabtest <- diabgen(AB,sex,eth) it returns an empty array.

If I can give further info that might make what i am talking about clearer please let me know I would be more than happy to do so, it seems so easy but it is doing my head in. I am open to any suggestions on other/better ways of doing the same thing, any hints appreciated.

Comment: The first argument of `runif` is the number of samples you want, probably 1.

Comment: Hi Vincent,  Thanks for that but I was wanting to do a random draw per individual which is why I ran the runif through the number of individuals in the age bracket rather than just one cycle. If I did one random draw and used it for all individuals and for example it was very low the simulation would indicate that everyone had diabetes, thanks for the interest.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to construct a dataframe with age, sex and ethnicity as factors?

Comment: Hi, I couldn't think of a data frame structure where I could get a value for someone while referencing 3 different variables, for two factors I can see easily but to get age bracket, sex, and ethnicity is why I went for a multi dimensional array.  If you have a suggestion on how to do it with a data frame I am all ears,thanks for the interest and the question.

Comment: You can convert your array to a data.frame with the `melt` function, from the `reshape` (or `reshape2`) package.

Comment: Hi Vincent, I see how your solution is similar to Adams below, thanks for the help, appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This maybe doesn't solve your problem (I'll update as needed), but it is a simple simulated dataframe for your conditions (2x11x6 factors)

```
brackets <- round(seq(15, 85, length.out = 12))
brlabels <- character()
for (i in 1:11) {
  brlabels[i] <- paste(brackets[i], "to", brackets[i + 1], sep = " ")
}
AB <- cut(round(runif(100, 18, 80)), breaks = brackets, labels = brlabels)

sex <- factor(sample(c(1,2), 100, replace = TRUE), levels = c(1,2), labels = c("Male", "Female"))

eth <- factor(sample(c(1:6), 100, replace = TRUE), levels = c(1:6), labels = c("French", "German", "Swedish", "Polish", "Greek", "Italian"))

somerandombusiness <- rnorm(100, 50, 4)

sim.df <- data.frame(somerandombusiness)
sim.df$AB <- AB
sim.df$sex <- sex
sim.df$eth <- eth
```

It may be more cumbersome to select a specific intersection of the three at first, but most of the tools to deal with factor variables expect a dataframe.

**Edit 1**

You could do something like:

```
runif(1,0) >= (sim.df[which(sim.df$AB=="34 to 40"&sim.df$sex=="Male"&sim.df$eth=="German"), 1])
```

But I'm still not sure why you would want to. For one, with my method there is no way to be sure that all possible combinations are enumerated. You could up the sample size to a few thousand without much trouble but that would only make it really really likely that every combination existed. In this case I've chose one that does exist.

You could do this more easily w/ something like `table(sim.df$eth, sim.df[, 1] > 60)` which will give a cross-tab of all the `somerandombusiness` values > 60 and various ethnicities.

Comment: Hi Adam, Thanks alot for the effort you have put in, I see what you mean now. So to select a specific value for the prevalence of diabetes in X age group of Y gender and Z ethnicity i would use something along the lines of: ifelse( runif(1,0,)>= (sim.df[which(sim.df$AB=="x"&sim.df$sex=="y"&sim.df$eth=="z")]),0,1) . Thanks for your help, had got stuck in a rut of thinking and could see any other options.

Comment: Assuming the `somerandombusiness` is the value we want, we can do something like: `sim.df[sim.df[, "sex"] == "Male" & sim.df[, "eth"] == "Greek", 1]` to select men from Greece

Comment: Hi Adam, to explain, purpose of this is to assign a binary variable to indicate that the simulated individual either does or doesn't have diabetes. I have prevalence data from other surveys broken down by the categories above (age bracket, gender, eth) which I am using to weight the chances of an individual with X characteristics having diabetes which is what is driving the need to look up the values. The broader idea is the generation of a simulated pop based on New Zealand demographic data. The next step is the imputation of non-binary data (eg blood pressures) based on other sets of data.

Comment: Ok. I'll take another look. In that case you should remove your mark of "answered" for me so that more people will see this question in the mean time.

Comment: To follow up, used a loop to step through the source data.frame (DF1) and pulled the relevant variables at each step and used them to look up the reference value from the data frame (DF2) holding the diabetes prevalence data. I then run a Bernoulli trial based on the the prevalence in DF2 and export the result (diabetes/not diabetes) back to the main dataframe. Thanks to Adam and Vincent for the help.